# Linux Mint 16 - Lock Screen Firmware Bug

Tags: linux, linux-mint, firmware

After playing around with a lot of dual-boot configurations, I've recently decided to ditch Windows (8.1) altogether and have installed Linux Mint.

I am running **Mint 16 Petra with MATE Desktop**

This issue hasn't caused any harm that I know of, and hasn't really interfered with anything.

When I lock my laptop, or just close the lid, I open it up to find a few lines being spat out at me saying I have a firmware bug. They are quickly replaced by the dialog box requesting for my password to unlock the computer, but I have managed to take a picture of the errors.

They are a series of errors that say:

```
[*some numbers*] [Firmware Bug]: cpu *X*, try to use APIC500 (LVT offset 0)
for vector *some hex*, but the register is already in use for vector *more hex*
on another cpu
```

- It seems the *some numbers* are different each time
- The *X* is either cpu 1, 2, or 3 (in sequence for each line)
- The first set of hex is always **0x400**
- The second set of hex is always **0xf9**

My Laptop:

- TOSHIBA Satellite S855D Version PSKG2U-028005
- AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon HD Graphics
- **Kernel**: 3.11.0-12-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.1)
- **Bios**: Insyde **Version**: 6.30

Has anyone had experience with this? Need anymore info on the computer or distro?

Comment: This issue actually causes a system slow-down for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More info [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1152484)

Seems it is a BIOS bug that is very common on AMD platforms.